# How can I separate TabLayout and ViewPager actions?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a standard setup between the two but I want the TabLayout's tap (when the user touches the TabLayout's dots directly) to be different than the ViewPager's swipe. Maybe I just want the tap action to print "tap" and the swipe action to print "swipe". At the moment, I haven't set anything on the TabLayout other than attaching it to the ViewPager, yet when I swipe on the ViewPager it prints both "swipe" and "tap".

Comment: You will not be able to use `setupWithViewPager()`, as it expects tab taps and page swipes to do the same thing. You would need to manage it all more manually, via custom listeners on the `TabLayout`. IMHO, from a usability standpoint, what you propose is unlikely to meet with user approval.

Comment: I got it eventually, but I also used setupWithViewPager().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it took some fiddling, but I finally got what I want. It turns out that the TabLayout's listeners care what the ViewPager deals with, but not the other way around. So when the VP is swiped, both listeners hear it. When the TabLayout is tapped, only the TabLayout is aware. Therefore, I can set the tap function to do its tap thing, and then in the swipe function I just have to make sure that it can figure out whether it was a swipe or a tap that actually moved the VP.

MVVM ViewModel binding:

```
@BindingAdapter({"onAdapterChangeListener"})
public static void setOnAdapterChangeListener(ViewPager viewPager, BehaviorSubject<Void> adapterChangeSubject) {
    viewPager.addOnAdapterChangeListener((viewPager1, oldAdapter, newAdapter) -> adapterChangeSubject.onNext(null));
}

@BindingAdapter({"viewPager","onTap","onSwipe"})
public static void addOnTabSelectedListener(TabLayout tabLayout, ViewPager viewPager, BehaviorSubject<Integer> tapSubject, BehaviorSubject<Integer> swipeSubject) {
    viewPager.addOnAdapterChangeListener((viewPager1, oldAdapter, newAdapter) -> {
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                int tabPosition = tab.getPosition();
                if (tabPosition == viewPager.getCurrentItem()) {
                    swipeSubject.onNext(tabPosition);
                    // A swipe will have the VP tell the TabLayout what tab to move to before
                    // this is called, so if the two positions match, it means the user
                    // performed a swipe action
                } else {
                    tapSubject.onNext(tabPosition);
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tabPosition);
                    // Otherwise, it was definitely a tap action
                }
            }
            // If I updated from API 23 to 24 I would use tabLayout.addOnTab and wouldn't
            // need these guys below
            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}
            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {}
        });
    });
}
```

XML:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-17dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/dot_tab_selector"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
        app:tabPaddingEnd="5dp"
        app:tabPaddingStart="5dp"
        app:viewPager="@{{viewPager}}"
        app:onTap="@{carouselViewModel.tapSubject}"
        app:onSwipe="@{carouselViewModel.swipeSubject}"/>

    <com.snip.CustomViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        app:onAdapterChangeListener="@{carouselViewModel.carouselAdapterChangeSubject}"/>
```

CarouselViewModel:

```
swipeSubject
            .subscribe(page -> {
                doTheSwipeThing();
            });

    tapSubject
            .subscribe(page -> {
                    doTheTapThing();
            });
```